Lazy loading or other similar options in Dash
I have 2 dropdowns - name and tag.
At the moment, the data is stored in cache (dcc.Store) and I do a callback according to the dropdown values,  and return a container with the filtered df as df_content:
container = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col([
        html.Div([
  
       html.A(f"{name}: {title}", href=link, className='h5', target='_blank') if link != "No link available"
       
       else html.Span(f"{name}: {title}", className = 'h5', style={ 'text-decoration': 'none'}),
       
       html.P(f'''{date} {content if content else ''}''', className="mt-2")
        ], className="p-3 mb-2 bg-light border")
        for name, title, date, content, link in zip(df_content['name'], df_content['title'], df_content['date'], df_content['content'], df_content['link'])

return container

the data is huge (750k+). Pretty new to web dev and dash. Is there a way to do a lazy load in dash or something similar so it can load some initial data and load incrementally and not crash?

it's the browser that'll kill you so it depends on what you want to "see".
If tabular then
https://dash.plotly.com/dash-ag-grid
If charts then
if timeseries then https://github.com/predict-idlab/plotly-resampler
if other then https://datashader.org/

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
